# PowerShell. Catch error. How add body to Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: rest, powershell

I need to add  this model:

```
{ "sourceVersion": "5ddcada97436a83dfedf5b41261ef9bfb8b718d7", "debug": true }
```

but PowerShell Console shows me Error "Bad Request."

This is my Code:

```
try {
    $serverHost = "api.appcenter.ms"
    $service = "https://$serverHost/v0.1/apps/App/App/branches/dev/builds" 
    $ContentType = "application/json" # Add the content type
    $Method = 'POST' # Add the method type
    $Body = '{ "sourceVersion" = "5ddcada97436a83dfedf5b41261ef9bfb8b718d7",     "debug" = True }'
    $Headers = @{'accept'='application/json';'X-API-    Token'='efa699e279155919d4ed7ca880e335ebd7ad8191'}

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $service -Headers $Headers -    Body $Body
    Read-Host -Prompt $result 
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
    Read-Host -Prompt "The above error occurred. Press Enter to exit."
}
```

Comment: `'X-API-    Token'`?

Comment: PowerShell automatically converts payload objects to the string representation needed. See [`Get-Help Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Assuming all else is correct, try fixing `X-API-     Token` to `X-API-Token` also remove the spaces between `-     Body`  Doing this I get a 404 error